# Alterações em outras branchs no tfs aparecem na branch em que atuo

Tags: visual-studio, versionamento, team-foundation-server

Não conheço muito o **TFS**. Porém uma coisa está me deixando louco. Sempre que abro uma determinada **BRANCH** para trabalhar, ao terminar e vou em **PENDING CHANGES** para fazer **checkin** e vejo que além das alterações que foram feitas, aparecem alterações não **comitadas** de outras **BRANCHS**. Então eu fico dando **Exclude**. Meu colega disse para eu **comitar** todos esses arquivos que eu dou **Exclude**, porem fico receoso de afetar o projeto de forma irreparável, pois muitos são exclusões(delete). Mas o que mais me intriga são alterações de outras **Branchs** que aparecerem na **Branch** que estou trabalhando. A pergunta é: Tem como evitar que esses arquivos apareçam e deixar apenas as alterações da **Branch** atual? Evitar os **Exclude**

Comment: Você esta trabalhando com Git? Qual a versão do seu TFS?

Comment: Não, apenas com tfs. Cara não sei a versão. Como eu vejo isso? TFS

Comment: O TFS nas versões mais recentes possuem dois tipos de versionadores de código: Git e TFVC, é preciso saber qual deles você está usando.

Você tem acesso ao servidor que o TFS está instalado? A maneira mais facil é o menu Help > About disponível no console do TFS.

Comment: TFS, esse é o que eu estou usando. Team Foundation Server(TFS) e Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition